# Angular child component doesn't work in two parent components

Tags: angular

There is a weird issue in my parent-to-child component and I will simplify it to be usable for everyone.

Components Structure:

```
ProfileEditComponent
-- ProfilePhotoEditComponent
-------- PhotoUploadComponent
-- AlbumPhotoEditComponent
-------- PhotoUploadComponent
```

There is a Child Component that I Call `PhotoUploadComponent`, And there are two components `ProfilePhotoEditComponent` and `AlbumPhotoEditComponent` that are using the `PhotoUploadComponent`. The problem is that `PhotoUploadComponent` does not work at the same time in both parent components. To be more clear `ProfilePhotoEditComponent` is on the top level at the DOM and `PhotoUploadComponent` works properly in the `ProfilePhotoEditComponent` but it does not work in the `AlbumPhotoEditComponent`. If I remove the tag
of `PhotoUploadComponent` form `ProfilePhotoEditComponent` HTML so the `PhotoUploadComponent` will work properly in the `AlbumPhotoEditComponent`.

I have to say that parent Components are located in another component and there is the same route for all of them. Actually, I have a tab feature that consists of `ProfilePhotoEditComponent` and `AlbumPhotoEditComponent`.

here is the code

**`ProfileEditComponent.html`**

```
<div class="tab-content ">

   <div class="tab-pane" id="Album">
     <app-profileAlbumPhotoEdit [member]="member"></app-profileAlbumPhotoEdit>
   </div>

   <div class="tab-pane" id="ProfilePhoto">
      <app-profilePhotoEdit [member]="member"></app-profilePhotoEdit>
   </div>

</div>
```

**`ProfilePhotoEditComponent.html`**

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <app-photo-upload [uploadPhoto]="uploadPhotoInfo"></app-photo-upload>
    </div>
```

**`ProfilePhotoEditComponent.ts`**

```
export class ProfilePhotoEditComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() member: Member;
uploadPhotoInfo : UploadPhoto = {
  url: "Users/AddPhoto",
  className: "square"
};

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**`AlbumPhotoEditComponent.html`**

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <app-photo-upload [uploadPhoto]="uploadPhotoInfo"></app-photo-upload>
    </div>
```

**`AlbumPhotoEditComponent.ts`**

```
export class AlbumPhotoEditComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() member: Member;
uploadPhotoInfo : UploadPhoto = {
  url: "UserAlbum/AddPhoto",
  className: "square"
};

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**`PhotoUploadComponent.ts`**

```
export class PhotoUploadComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() uploadPhoto: UploadPhoto;
  uploader:FileUploader;

  constructor (private accountService: AccountService){
   this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(u => this.user = u); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.InitializeUploader(); 
    this.DragDrop();
  }



  InitializeUploader() {
  this.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: this.baseUrl + this.uploadPhoto.url,
    authToken: 'Bearer ' + this.user.token,
    isHTML5: true,
    allowedFileType: ['image'],
    removeAfterUpload: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    maxFileSize: 10 * 1024* 1024
    
  });

  this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {
    file.withCredentials = false;
  }

  this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => {
    if (response) {
      const photo = JSON.parse(response);
    }
  }

 }
}
```

**`PhotoUploadComponent.html`**

```
   <div class="drag-area" ng2FileDrop [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
  (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)" [uploader]="uploader">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i></div>
  <header>Drag & Drop to Upload File</header>
  <span>OR</span>
  <button>Browse File</button>
  <input style="display: none;" title="Upload ypur photo" type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" type="file"
      hidden>
```

In the `PhotoUploadComponent` I'm using [ng2-file-upload](https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) to upload images.

Update:
Upload functionality and the pop-up window does not appear when I'm going to upload a new file. And there is no error in the console as well.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Any errors? Also, what is this.InitializeUploader(); do?

Comment: is the user in PhotoUploadComponent used in what "doesn't work" ? It is hard to help you more without knowing what you mean by doesn't work: does it not display? does it display but the upload isn't made? etc...

Comment: Could you add the upload implementation and the popup implementation to the question please?

Comment: @Ocunidee  I updated the qustion

Comment: would you be able to put a breakpoint in the InitializeUploader method and check (when it doesn't work) if you have your full token in this.uploader.authToken

Comment: @Ocunidee Actually nothing happens When I click the upload button. and there is no error.